# Same text string inside function template

Tags: c++, templates

Is it better to keep long message string outside of function template, or do compilers always create one copy of the string in such cases? Should I put "Long error message" outside of the template function, e.g. in a separate `printError` function?

```
template<typename T>
function f( ARGS )
{
    if ( some_check(ARGS) ) 
        cout << "Long error message independent of T";

    ...
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

While the answer to that depends on what the linker supports, you can be reasonably sure that with any level of optimization turned on, the duplicate string literals will be merged into one.

In particular, GCC provides the option [`-fmerge-constants`](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Optimize-Options.html) which will merge identical constants, including string literals, across compilation units as long as the linker allows it. This is enabled at `-O, O2, O3 and -Os`. Similarly, LLVM has an optimization pass, [`-constmerge`](http://llvm.org/docs/Passes.html#constmerge-merge-duplicate-global-constants) which merges duplicate global constants.

Answer (score 1):

The compiler will probably create a copy of the string literal for each instance of the template, but unless you have several kilobytes of string I doubt that it'll have any real impact. If you do have an EXCESSIVELY long string, storing it outside of the function template will do the trick.

Comment: Further, most modern compilers allow you to enable a feature called `Merge duplicate string literals` or words to that effect. Worth researching on the OP's toolchain.